# Sencha- cordova app connection with backend

Tags: cordova, extjs, connection, backend

I wanted to know how it was possible to reach the backend from my application.
Normally, if I use a web application made in Sencha I just use an apache service in order to use the redirection of the IP address in order to reach my backend.
But when I create an app using Cordova, this is not possible.
How can I reach my backend if redirection services cannot be used on mobile devices?

thanks for the reply

Comment: `I just use an apache service in order to use the redirection of the IP address in order to reach my backend` sounds overly complicated. I use relative URLs to reach the backend, and in the cordova app, they are prepended with the server URL.

Comment: but how does it work? if I specify the IP when I make ajax calls,it do 'OPTIONS' calls

Comment: Only in a local browser, not in cordova, at least for me.